# Extracting multiple text using partial href information

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, href, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract multiple genre from below site. (I already know the URLs)
https://www.discogs.com/master/1515454-Zedd-Katy-Perry-365

```html
<div class="profile">
  <h1 id="profile_title" class="hide_mobile has_action)menu">...<h1>
  <div class="head">Genre:<div> ==$0
  <div class="content">
    <a href="/genre/electronic">Electronic</a>
    ", "
    <a href="/genre/pop">Pop</a>
```

---

And here's my Python code

```js
genre = None
try:
  genre = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' profile ')]//*[contains(@href, ' /genre/* '").text
```

How do I extract genres to text? (e.g. Electronic, Pop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract and print the values of ***Genre*** i.e. *`Electronic`*, *`Pop`*, etc within the [website](https://www.discogs.com/master/1515454-Zedd-Katy-Perry-365) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.discogs.com/master/1515454-Zedd-Katy-Perry-365")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr/th[@scope='row' and contains(., 'Genre')]//following::td[1]//a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Electronic', 'Pop']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Awesome, the data is currently extracting! :)

Comment: Thanks. The code is currently in 'for loop'. (reading and writing on excel - for many addresses) If URL meets no information, how do I pass and proceed to the next loop - instead of the 'TimeoutException' error message?

Comment: @MyoungNam Can you please raise a new question for your new requirement?